How to dispatched an Input event for a contenteditable and have it work?
I am trying to make text bold in a content editable by a button click.


const e = document.querySelector('#e');
const b = document.querySelector('#b');

e.addEventListener('input', (event) => {
  console.log('---');
  console.log('isTrusted', event.isTrusted);
  console.log('inputType', event.inputType);
});

b.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  e.dispatchEvent(new InputEvent('input', {
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: true,
    composed: true,
    inputType: 'formatBold',
  }));  
});
<button id="b">B</button>
<div id="e" contenteditable="true">
Hello World
</div>



I'm testing in Safari on MacOS:
If I highlight the word hello, right-click, select "Font" from the menu, then select "Bold", the highlighted word hello will bold. I will also see the input event as expected.
If I highlight the word hello, click the "B" button, the highlighted word hello will not bold. I still see the event as expected (but it is not trusted).
How do I dispatch an input event and have it work?

I am pretty sure that the isTrusted flag exist purely to tell the difference between events thrown by the browser and through js code ran through a script- check out the mdn docs. This ensures that people can not spoof events that seem real through the console or other scripts.
